# Instagram media loading delay via WireGuard and 3x-ui

Tags: vpn, vps, wireguard

I am from russia and I have some problems with VPN. As you may know, insta and all meta products are banned in my country so the only way to use instagram is using VPN. And i have some issues with WireGuard and 3x-ui with VLESS: when i open instagram app it is loading only text, no stories/photo/video is loading for first 15-20 seconds. After waiting it starts downloading them pretty fast but delay is pissing me off. All other sites are loading pretty fast, speedtest says that my speed is approx. 130 mbps. via my home wifi. btw all free and unsafe VPN's from play market/app store that are still not banned in my country are loading all content without delay.

p.s. i am not the only one using this vps, there are 7 more people using it and they have the same issue

p.p.s. i have a friend of mine that is using wireguard too on turkish vps and he is facing the same issue. So i guess this is problem of VPS/wireguard/3x-ui

- i installed warp on my finnish VPS, made instagram go through it via 3x-ui settings but it didn't help
- also i tried different dns on wireguard when creating profiles but it doesnt help either

Comment: I found out that it is because of instagram CDN servers. As i understand, they do not like the http connection, only https will connect you immediately. I'm still figuring out what to do now

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/XTLS/Xray-core/discussions/1915) conversation, 3x-ui's implementation of wireguard (xray core) is not the fastest one. Have you tried using other control panels, that utilize kernel's wireguard?

When I was using wireguard (until 08-2023), wg-easy and some other panels have not produced this issue.